# Update nested array document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

say i have this model

```
{
    _id : 1,
    ref: '1',
    children: [
    {
        ref:'1.1',
        grandchildren: [
            {
                ref:'1.1.1',
                visible: true;
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm aware that positional operator for nested arrays isn't available yet.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

but wondered whether its possible to atomically update the document in the nested array?

In my example, i'd like to update the `visible` flag to false for the document for ref 1.1.1.

I have the children record ref == '1.1' and the grandchildrenref == '1.1.1'

thanks

Comment: Given your data model, couldn't it be implied that '1.1.1' if the first child of '1.1' which in its turn if the first child of '1' ? If your embedded documents are ordered and you don't have hole -- this is trivially solved: `{$set: {"children.0.grandchildren.0.visible":"false"}}` -- But I'm pretty sure this couldn't be so easy... ;)

Comment: yeah, thats kind of the point though. i don't know which child it is, the open jira issue, when completed will support exactly this, so as long as the filter can identify as least one of each positional referenced array element, the `$` operator will select the correct document from the nested array.  this only real solution i can think of now is to limit document array nesting to 1. thanks for comment though

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible only if you knew the index of the children array that has the grandchildren object to be updated beforehand and the update query will use the positional operator as follows:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "children.ref": "1.1",
        "children.grandchildren.ref": "1.1.1"
    }, 
    {
        "$set": { 
            "children.0.grandchildren.$.visible": false
        }
    }
)
```

However, if you don't know the array index positions beforehand, you should consider creating the **`$set`** conditions dynamically by using **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)**. The basic idea with MapReduce is that it uses JavaScript as its query language but this tends to be fairly slower than the aggregation framework and not recommended for use in real-time data analysis.

In your MapReduce operation, you need to define a couple of steps i.e. the mapping step (which maps an operation into every document in the collection, and the operation can either do nothing or emit some object with keys and projected values) and reducing step (which takes the list of emitted values and reduces it to a single element).

For the map step, you ideally would want to get for every document in the collection, the index for each `children` array field and another key that contains the `$set` keys.

Your reduce step would be a function (which does nothing) simply defined as `var reduce = function() {};`

The final step in your MapReduce operation will then create a separate collection operations that contains the emitted operations array object along with a field with the `$set` conditions. This collection can be updated periodically when you run the MapReduce operation on the original collection.
Altogether, this MapReduce method would look like:

```
var map = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
        emit( 
            {
                "_id": this._id, 
                "index": i 
            }, 
            {
                "index": i, 
                "children": this.children[i],            
                "update": {
                    "ref": "children." + i.toString() + ".grandchildren.$.ref",
                    "visible": "children." + i.toString() + ".grandchildren.$.visible"
                }                    
            }
        );
    }
};

var reduce = function(){};

db.collection.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {
        "out": {
            "replace": "update_collection"
        }
    }
);
```

You can then use the cursor from the `db.update_collection.find()` method to iterate over and update your collection accordingly:

```
var cur = db.update_collection.find(
    {
        "value.children.ref": "1.1",
        "value.children.grandchildren.ref": "1.1.1" 
    }
);

// Iterate through results and update using the update query object set dynamically by using the array-index syntax.
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    var update = { "$set": {} };
    // set the update query object
    update["$set"][doc.value.update.visible] = false;

    db.collection.update(
        {
            "children.ref": "1.1",
            "children.grandchildren.ref": "1.1.1"
        }, 
        update 
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks chridam, that's certainly an answer.  i'm using the c# driver, and dropping back to server side MR javascript seems a massive overkill.  From what i understand from your example, it wouldn't be a single atomic find and update, but rather find, iterate, update - leaving it prone to consistency problems. please correct me if i'm incorrect.  it's a shame as the particular case i have is for a doc with two level array, perfectly suited to a single document for the entity.  thanks for your help, i'm going to resort to multiple entity/collections until a better solution is available. thanks!

Comment: @sambomartin No worries. You are definitely correct about the overkill in the MR workaround as your document schema has nested arrays of which the positional operator cannot be applied here for an atomic update. Good luck with your project for now.