# Match and update a node based on its content

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "doc_id": 1234,
    "pars": [
      {
        "par_id": 4567,
        "someNode": "...",
        "lines": [
          {
            "line_id": 8901,
            "someOtherNode": "...",
            "text": "Foo"
          }, 
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I update the `text` field in the right node knowing `doc_id`, `par_id` and `line_id` ?

I cannot use this query, as I don't have the node indexes that correspond to `par_id` and `line_id`

```
con.db.col.update(
    {'_id': doc_id},
    {'$set': { "pars.?.lines.?.text": "Bar" } }
)
```

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019015/update-nested-array-document

Comment: Also worth tracking the JIRA https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 0):

[Because updating based on a match in nested arrays is not yet supported in MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831), you'll need to rearrange your schema. Right now you have an array of paragraphs, each of which is an array of lines. I suggest making paragraphs a *document* whose fieldnames are paragraphIds, rather than an array. You can keep the lines as an array, and you can then update by paragraphId and lineId using the ["$" positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
> db.collection.insertOne({
...   "doc_id": 1234,
...   "pars": {
...     4567: {
...       "someNode": "...",
...       "lines": [
...         {
...           "line_id": 8901,
...           "someOtherNode": "...",
...           "text": "Foo"
...         },
...       ]
...     }
...   }
... })
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("58ecb95e475838c0db6efd9d")
}
> db.collection.updateOne({
...   "doc_id": 1234,
...   "pars.4567.lines.line_id": 8901
... }, {
...   "$set": {"pars.4567.lines.$.text": "Bar"}
... })
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.collection.findOne({"doc_id": 1234})
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58ecb95e475838c0db6efd9d"),
  "doc_id" : 1234,
  "pars" : {
    "4567" : {
      "someNode" : "...",
      "lines" : [
        {
          "line_id" : 8901,
          "someOtherNode" : "...",
          "text" : "Bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this-

```
db.col.update(
    {"_id": doc_id, "par_id": 4567,  "pars.lines.line_id":8901},
    {$set: { "pars.$.lines.$.text":"ANY_TEXT_YOU_WANT" } },
function(){}  //callback function)
```

Comment: No, two "$" operators aren't supported.

Comment: OOPS use this -:                                                                         
  `{$set: { "pars.lines.$.text":"ANY_TEXT_YOU_WANT" } }`

Answer (score -1):

$$ is the special operator (new positional operator)

you can do something like this-

```
db.col.update(
    {"_id": doc_id, "par_id": 4567,  "pars.lines.line_id":8901},
    {$set: { "pars.lines.$$.text":"ANY_TEXT_YOU_WANT" } },
function(){}  //callback function)
```